# How to handle CSRF Validation in Yii2 Framework?

Tags: php, csrf, yii2

I'm having problem with CSRF Validation in yii2. The validation works fine with the default form generated by the gii but when I edit the form with html tags then the form submission throws a bad request error. I have disabled csrf validation to  hide the error but I want to use this for the security of the application and data validation.

Is there any way of solving this error or is there a way of configuring it to work correctly in this scenario?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to assume what can cause this problem. Please add form changes that broke CSRF validation.

Comment: <form id="w0" class="form-horizontal" action="/pofil/backend/deposit/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="Ry1JRjA3QnouHC8IegZ1Pgp1LQV9XDcpGAADIF5WATAuYAwnYQAhLQ==">
    <div class="form-group field-page-title required">
<label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="page-title">Title</label>
<div class="col-sm-11">
<input type="text" id="page-title" class="form-control" name="Page[title]" maxlength="500">
    </form>

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting it as comment,

Answer (score 51):

I guess, your html form doesn't have hidden `_csrf` field, which is automatically generated by standard Yii2 widgets.

So the minimum code of your custom form might be like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfParam; ?>" value="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfToken; ?>" />
    <button type="submit"> Save </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I've only changed the form input element with custom html element and my form element include the csrf value with name that is generated by the gii. i don't know what's happening.

Comment: I have hidden _csrf param in my Yii2 form and autogenerated token as its value. But anyway my app.log is full of BadRequestHttpException entries, even though the form data is stored normally. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
<?=yii\helpers\Html::hiddenInput(Yii::$app->request->csrfParam, Yii::$app->request->csrfToken)?>
```