# Yii2 accepting POST data in action - Invalid route?

Tags: controller, http-post, yii2, http-verbs

I may be missing something with a basic concept of Yii2 but I am simply trying to submit a form to a controller action and when that happens I am always getting `InvalidRouteException`. The controller is called "List" and is class `ListController` which extends `Controller`.

To my understanding I need to setup the `Urlmanager` to allow the controller to accept POST and then setup a verb filter to allow the controller to accept POST on the specific action.

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'POST list/search' => 'list/search',
         ]


'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'search' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: I don't think that the rules section is necessary. You could remove this. And where is your VerbFilter, in the Controller? Which URL is called?

Comment: Yes, its in the controller.
class ListController extends Controller

Comment: Please update your question to make this clear. And tell us which URL is called.

Comment: The controller is called "List" (ListController).  I will also add that i am not using the active form class, but rather just a straight form tag. Is there possibly something in place with CSRF that active form uses that would block a request from coming in as POST and send me to the error exception?

Comment: Could be! Though I would expect an BadRequest error. Look [here](http://zero-exception.blogspot.co.at/2015/01/yii2-using-csrf-token.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473298/how-to-handle-csrf-validation-in-yii2-framework) for more information about that. Why don't you edit your post and tell us the URL you are calling, how your form and controller look like and tell us exactly where that mentioned config for verb and urlManager is?

Comment: Have you tried removing the rule from the urlManager?