# Unable to verify your data submission bad request (#400) in yii2 (if select video format)

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, fileinputstream, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i am new yii2, so i have this problem. i want to use fileinput so i add fileinput 
this url  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html
if i create new model with file input (select video) and if i delete item in model  so:**
Ber Request (#400) 
Unable to verify your data submission. 
if i select image, it work ok
how to upload video in yii2 ?

my log:

```
exception 'yii\web\BadRequestHttpException' with message 'Unable to verify your data submission.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php:110
Stack trace:
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(149): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('delete', Array)
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(84): yii\base\Module->runAction('music/delete', Array)
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\web\index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
{main}
```

Please, help me? Thank !

Answer (score 9):

It's code from core YII2.

```
if ($this->enableCsrfValidation && Yii::$app->getErrorHandler()->exception === null && !Yii::$app->getRequest()->validateCsrfToken()) {
    throw new BadRequestHttpException(Yii::t('yii', 'Unable to verify your data submission.'));
}
```

Try turn off csrf validation.

```
MyController extends Controller {
    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
}
```

Comment: thank, i found answer. this problem - my php configiration. it don't access to upload 2 M files (php >> php.ini file)

Comment: It works for me, thanks a lot. But why we need to disable csrf validation, can anyone explain where we need to enable Csrf validation and where we need to disable Csrf validation?

Comment: Best way is always use csrf. This sample just helps to understand problem. How to handle csrf you can see there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28479422/2655835

Answer (score 0):

See Upgrade instructions:

[https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md#upgrade-from-yii-20-beta][1]

> Please update your main layout file by adding this line in the 
>   section: `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>` . This change is needed because
>   yii\web\View no longer automatically generates CSRF meta tags due to
>   issue #3358

Comment: I have this line in my layout head section, but my app.log is full of BadRequestHttpException entries, even though the form data is stored normally. What am I doing wrong?