# How To use Jquery Ajax in YII framework

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

```
$('#update-info').on('click',function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . 'ajax'?>',
        //data: {name: properties.filename},
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("failure");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: google it, you will find your answer, if still d not get, then post your program here

Comment: i cant find a specific answer or procedure to use that thats why i posted here

Comment: if you show your code, then i can help you.

Comment: you are using yii2 syntax in java script it wont work. give url like ?r=action_name/controller_name

Comment: http://localhost:8080/site/ajax  url which is being called

Comment: this should call ajax $('#update-info').on('click',function() { 
 $.ajax({ url: 'site/ajax', //
 data: {name: properties.filename}, 
 type: "POST", success: function () { 
 console.log("success"); 
 }, 
 error: function () { 
 console.log("failure"); 
 } }); });

Comment: I tried that it says 400 bad request

Comment: this means you data section is having issue, can you check value of properties.filename

Comment: it worked my csrf token was not false  when i was making ajax request

Comment: csrf token is something you should not disable. it compromise security

Comment: if i pass this token in data filed? how can we pass it

Comment: but the issue was with csrf token i just added beforeAction method in my controller which disabled csrf token value to false

Comment: this csrf issue is solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473298/how-to-handle-csrf-validation-in-yii2-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it as everywhere else:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "controller/action", // here your URL address
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
});
```

Modify `url` to match your address for ajax request.

Comment: i am using this it says 403 forbidden access

Comment: So the problem is propably in behaviors in controller. Update question with controller code.

Comment: Bad Request (#400): Unable to verify your data submission.

Comment: in controller action add `$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;`